# Mutating Infix Functions for Structs Swift

Tags: swift, infix-operator

So say I have a `Vector` structure:

```
struct Vector
{
    var x: Double = 0
    var y: Double = 0

    init(x: Double, y: Double)
    {
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    }
}
```

And I create an infix function that adds two `Vector` structures:

```
func +(left: Vector, right: Vector) -> Vector
{
    return Vector(left.x + right.x, left.y + right.y)
}
```

This works well, but then when I want to create an infix function that adds two `Vectors` together and sets the left value to the result (like `+=`), then it doesn't work:

```
func +=(left: Vector, right: Vector)
{
    left.x += right.x
    left.y += right.y
}
```

When I try it in my code, it doesn't do anything. If I change the `Vector` structure into a class, then it works.

I know that Swift copies `structs` and references `classes`, so is there a way to do this or is this impossible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `+=` function on its current form, you're attempting to mutate members of an immutable *value* type, which are, themselves, immutable. If you add the `inout` keyword to `left` in the function signature, this value type will become mutable and its mutation updated via `inout`:s copy-in-copy-out behaviour (compiler optimization: in practice by reference to avoid copy overhead, if possible), whereafter your `+=` function will work as intended.

```
func +=(left: inout Vector, right: Vector)
{
    left.x += right.x
    left.y += right.y
}
```

The reason your initial function worked for class types is that an the members of an immutable reference type are, themselves, mutable; only the reference itself may not be mutated.

Answer (score 2):

Just add the inout parameter for your left param so that the value
will be saved:

```
func += (left: inout Vector, right: Vector)
{
  left.x += right.x
  left.y += right.y
}
```